# Is it possible to install Mac OS 9 on a VM?

Tags: virtualization, classic-mac-os

Recently I got hold of a Mac OS 9.2.1 retail CD and would like to test drive it in a VM.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SheepShaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net) will be your best bet. There's several tutorials laying around on getting OS 9 running in SheepShaver.

Answer (score 2):

All OS 9 capable machines run on the PowerPC platform, meaning that your VM software has to emulate that instead of the x86 platform.

These are pretty rare.  I know only of qemu which can emulate multiple platforms, and it is mostly suited for technicians.  I would go for a dedicated OS 9 emulator as suggested by https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64963/3157

Answer (score 0):

Sheepshaver only runs 9.0.4  therefor Mac OS 9.2.1 will not work. because sheepshaver can only emulate a Macintosh 9600. Not a Power Mac G4 or G3 iMac or even a G3 Powermac

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score -2):

it would not work in vmware/virtulbox but it would work in qemu manager

Comment: Why? an answer should explain - and how does this improve on this [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64975/237)?