# Play Floppy Disk Game on my macbook

Tags: floppy

My husband loves this game, called Hellcats Over the Pacific, that I really want to figure out how he can play. It is a 1991 Macintosh floppy disk. 
Is there a way I can play this on my macbook with a floppy disk drive and a virtual environment? I know there are some ways to get data from floppy disks, but can you actually play these old games without an ancient computer?
Any advice from someone who was successfully accomplished this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64961/is-it-possible-to-install-mac-os-9-on-a-vm) might give you some pointers